# Android hide tab in android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-tablayout

Is there a way to dynamically hide and show a tab in `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`

For example, click a button/view somewhere else in activity which hides or shows the tab in position 3 or shows/hides tab of a specific id.

I tried removing the tab `tabLayout.removeTabAt(3);` and add it back in but get an exception when swiping tabs as swipe still tries to go to the tab that has been removed

```
12-08 12:30:42.904  29052-29052/com.example.p1v1 E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
```

I have the following code:

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
...
...

public class BaseTabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_w,
            R.drawable.ic_x,
            R.drawable.ic_y,
            R.drawable.z
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_tab);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    ...
    ...

    }



    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FeedFragment(), "W");
        adapter.addFragment(new FeedFragment(), "X");
        adapter.addFragment(new FeedFragment(), "Y");
        adapter.addFragment(new FeedFragment(), "Z");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            //return mFragmentTitleList.get(position); //replace below with this if you want tab text and not just icons

            // return null to display only the icon
            return null;

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: have you tried tab_layout.setVisibility(View.Gone) and tab_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Comment: that is to show hide the entire tab layout, i want to show hide a specific tab in the layout

Comment: any update? I am facing a similar problem

Comment: No update I am afraid, i could not resolve so I changed my design instead